# How do I show that $\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{x+4}{x+1} - \frac1{\log(x+1)} \right)$ does not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the following limit. $$L = \lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{x+4}{x+1} - \frac1{\log(x+1)} \right)$$

By graphing it, I can see that $L \to -\infty$ as $x\to 0^+$ and $L\to +\infty$ as $x\to 0^-$. So the limit not only doesn't exits, but also it diverges on both sides. But I am not sure how to actually prove this or show why this is the case. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x+4}{x+1}=4,$$your limit exists if and only if the limit$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{\log(x+1)}$$exists. But it does not exist:

- since $\lim_{x\to0}\log(x+1)=0$ and since $x>0\implies\log(x+1)>0$, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1{\log(x+1)}=\infty$;
- since $\lim_{x\to0}\log(x+1)=0$ and since $x<0\implies\log(x+1)<0$, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac1{\log(x+1)}=-\infty$.